# Ubuntu ssh client how to specify non-standard port for connecting to ssh server on 2nd ubuntu machine

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh, client

I am new to SSH.  Two ubuntu machines on home network.  Ubuntu 20.04 server on one, Ubuntu 16.04 on 2nd machine used as SSH client.

Client succefsully logs into server with standard port 22, that is, no change made to sshd_config file on server.

However, on the server, if the sshd_config file has the "#  port22" line un-commented and changed to read "    port 2227" (or anything besides 22)  what needs to be changed on the client machine?

If I change the port number (on the server) I cannot ssh into the server from the client machine.  For example if I un-comment (on the server, in \etc\ssh\sshd_config) the #   port 22 so that it reads

```
Port 2227
```

Then from the client machine I enter:

```
ssh -p 2227 username@192.168.1.207
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.207 port 2227: Connection timed out
```

Figured there must be a way to configure the client so that this does not happen.

Or is it the UFW that needs to be tweaked?  From a windows10 machine it doesn't matter which port a choose (on the server) to listen for ssh, the windows10 client always connect if I specify the non-standard port.

Any and all suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: That looks like a server side issue - did you remember to reload the configuration (`sudo systemctl reload ssh`) or restart the service after changing the sshd_config file?

Comment: ... but yes if you are running UFW (or any other firewall) on the server you will need to revise the SSH rule to reflect the new port

Comment: That was it, thanks very much, steeldriver! "sudo ufw allow 2227/tcp" was all it took.  But why would the windows10 machines not have the same issue?